# VNC connection, xstartup?

Tags: 18.04, configuration, vnc, remote-access

I've setup two tunnels via a host with a public IP from my home computer, to my work computer:

```
work$ ssh -R 5901:localhost:5901 public
home$ ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 public
```

and when i connect by vnc from my home machine, I only get the grey screen with the three checkboxes. I've tried out various `xstartup` files and now have "dumbed" it down to just:

```
work$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
/usr/bin/gnome-session &

#[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xsetroot -solid grey
#vncconfig -iconic &
# x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &
```

it also is set executable:

```
work$ ls -l ~/.vnc/xstartup 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ron ron 391 Oct 15 04:56 /home/ron/.vnc/xstartup
```

and the running server instance looks like:

```
work$  ps ax | grep vnc
 9864 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto vnc
13747 ?        S      0:00 Xvnc4 :1 -desktop ecoationron:1 (ron) -auth /home/ron/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/ron/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -pn -fp /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb
13754 ?        S      0:00 vncconfig -iconic
```

What am I missing? Oh, the server is running on Ubuntu 18.04 and optimally, I would like to se the Unity desktop upon login by VNC.

Comment: AFAIK `exec` means "replace the current process with ..." so all the lines after that are ignored I think?

Comment: @steeldriver no, `exec` is used t call a forked process, calls afterwards are not ignored as far as i know